# I cannot open a file using macros in MASM

Tags: assembly, ubuntu-18.04, masm32, dosbox

I have a problem including a file and using a macro. I need to open a text file, for this I have created a macro in a separate file. The problem is that when I try to open the file when I use the macro, the system cannot open it and it goes to the error tag. However if I put the macro code inside the main function, it works fine. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.
I am using Dosbox on Ubuntu.

**main.asm**

```
include CAD.ASM
include ARC.ASM

spila segment stack
    DB 32 DUP ('stack___')
spila ends

sdatos segment
    RUTA DB 'test.xml', 00H
    ERR1 DB 'error: no se pudo abrir el archivo', '$'
    ERR2 DB 'error: no se pudo cerrar el archivo', '$'
    HAND DW ?
sdatos ends

scodigo segment 'CODE'
    
    ASSUME SS:spila, DS:sdatos, CS:scodigo         
    
    main PROC FAR 
        
        PUSH DS
        MOV  AX, 0
        PUSH AX
        MOV  AX, sdatos
        MOV  DS, AX                                 

        MOV AH, 3DH
        MOV AL, 02H
        LEA DX, RUTA
        INT 21H
        JC  msjError1
        MOV HAND, AX

        MOV AH, 3EH
        MOV BX, HAND
        INT 21H
        JC  msjError2
        JMP salir

        ;inicio:
        ;    abrirArchivo RUTA, HAND ; Doesn't work
        ;    cerrarArchivo HAND      ; Doesn't work
        msjError1:
            imprimirTexto ERR1
            JMP salir
        msjError2:
            imprimirTexto ERR2
            JMP salir
        salir:

        RET
    main endp
    
scodigo ends
end main
```

**cad.asm**

```
imprimirTexto MACRO string
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, string
    INT 21H
ENDM
```

**arc.asm**

```
abrirArchivo MACRO buffer, handler
    MOV AH, 3DH
    MOV AL, 02H
    LEA DX, buffer
    INT 21H
    JC  msjError1
    MOV handler, AX
ENDM

cerrarArchivo MACRO handler
    MOV AH, 3EH
    MOV BX, handler
    INT 21H
    JC  msjError2
ENDM
```

Comment: In arc.asm, I see `JC  msjError1`, so it will go to msjError1 if there's an error.  But what do you expect to happen if there is NOT an error?  It will do the `MOV`, then?  There is no way to avoid dropping in to `msjError1` here.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Thanks for answering. I'm actually just opening and closing the file, what I hope is that the error message is not displayed, as the file that I am trying to open does exist. But this only happens when I don't use the macro, when I use the macro it does show the error and it shouldn't since the file does exist.

Comment: How do you know that there's an error?  Because it prints the error message, right?  But the way your code is written, it will ALWAYS print the error, whether it succeeds or not.  Because after you call abrirArchivo  & cerrarArchivo, the very next instruction is msjError1.  So if it fails, the macro jumps to msjError1, and if it succeeds, it just falls thru to msjError1.  How about if after cerrarArchivo you add `JMP salir`?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Indeed that jump was what I was forgetting. Thank you.